# Panic: interface conversion: * is not inteface X: missing method xxx

Tags: go

I'm working on a project that consume messages from Kafka, unmushal using messagepack or json format, build sql of it and insert them into TDengine database.

The inteface defined as:

```golang
type TaosEncoder interface {
    TaosDatabase() string
    TaosSTable() string
    TaosTable() string
    TaosTags() []interface{}
    TaosCols() []string
    TaosValues() []interface{}
}
```

For an object called `Record`:

```golang
type Record struct {
    DeviceID  string        `json:"deviceID"` // for table name
    Timestamp time.Time     `json:"timestamp"`
    Cols      []interface{} `json:"cols"`
}
```

Implement the interface:

```golang
func (r *Record) TaosCols() []string {
    var tags []string
    return tags
}
// other methods are implemented too
```

A method will use the interface methods:

```golang
func ToTaosBatchInsertSql(l []interface{}) (string, error) {
    records := make([]string, len(l))
    for i, t := range l {
        // type TaosEncoderT = *TaosEncoder
        record, err := ToTaosRecordSql(t.(TaosEncoder))
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        records[i] = record
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("insert into %s", strings.Join(records, " ")), nil
}
```

Use it as this:

```golang
records := make([]interface{}, size)
for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
    item := <-q.queue # an channel of Record, defined as: queue chan interface{}
    records[i] = item
}
sqlStr, err := utils.ToTaosBatchInsertSql(records)
```

It compiles ok, but failed while running like this:

```golang
panic: interface conversion: record.Record is not utils.TaosEncoder: missing method TaosCols

goroutine 71 [running]:
xxx/pkg/utils.ToTaosBatchInsertSql(0xc000130c80, 0xc8, 0xc8, 0xc8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
```

But when I change the implementations of Record - remove `*`

```golang
func (r Record) TaosCols() []string {
    var tags []string
    return tags
}
```

Then it just works.

I've told to use `*` in interface implements, so the question is:

1. Is it ok to implement interface with `func (r Record) xxx`?
2. If not, what can I do?

Comment: Unrelated to my answer below: why are you using a `chan interface{}`, when it seems you know exactly what sole type you will be sending?

Comment: If your method needs to persist changes to the type, then you'll need a pointer receiver (`*Record`). To fix your runtime issue, ensure the values you are passing in via `interface{}` are `*Record`. But really if you already have an interface defined, your functions should take the `TaosEncoder` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this error is related to the method sets of a type.

Assume a type `T` that has methods with a receiver type of `T` and some more methods with a receiver type of `*T`.

Then, if a variable is of type `T`, it has all methods available that have a pointer receiver of `T` **but none of the methods with receiver type `*T`.**

If a variable is of type `*T`, it has both sets of methods available, those with receiver type `T`, and those with receiver type `*T`.

In your case, type `Record` has no `TaosCols()` method, and so it does not implement interface `TaosEncoder` completely.

If you turn the variable of type `Record` into a `*Record` variable, it has all methods available and then would implement the interface.

[Method Sets in: Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) - The Go Programming Language](https://golang.org/doc/faq#different_method_sets)

[Method Sets in: The Go Programming Language Specification - The Go Programming Language](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

Comment: This situation can be a bit confusing because the Go compiler implicitly takes the address of variables in some situations. Per https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls: “If `x` is addressable and `&x`'s method set contains `m`, `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`”. So in other places in the code, you may be able to call `t.TaosCols()` even though it is the pointer _to_ `t` that has the `TaosCols` method.

Answer (score 0):

A `Record` is not the same type as a `*Record`. If you use a pointer receiver for defining the methods that implement the interface, then only `*Record` implements `TaosEncoder`.

Based on this:

```
item := <-q.queue # an channel of Record
```

it looks like you will need to send a value of `*Record` on `q.queue`, rather than a `Record`.